# CURL gives empty response

Tags: elasticsearch, curl

I'm attempting to set up a manual back up process for elastic search with ansible.. but when I attempt to curl the elastic server page I get an empty response from the console.  No error message, no text, just empty.

I run curl https://website.etc.com:500 and that gives me an SSL error stating that the peers certificate issuer has been marked as not trusted by the user.

So I attempt to ignore ssl and curl -k url:port and it gives me a blank line in the console.

Why can't I curl this website???

Comment: elasticsearch default port is  9200. did you change it? also when you are using https. you need username and password.

Comment: Yes the port was changed, I also gave it a username and password by typing  curl --user username:password https://metrics.etc.etc